# Global/session scoped values in PHP

Tags: php, memcached, session-state, apc

Is there a standard way of dealing with globally scoped variables in PHP? Session scoped?

From the research I've done, it looks like the options are mostly add-ons or external. APC might work, but would be limited to a single PHP instance and not so useful for a farm of servers. *Memcached* seems like it would work, but I was hoping to find something within PHP.

Does its stateless approach keep there from being a standard method for handling this?

Answer (score 1):

A persistent layar is the only way to go with php. Either file based solution or database.

php natively doesn't provide any mechanism to do application scope variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can do session variables with [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).